# Use custom domain on Bluemix app

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've deployed an app to bluemix and currently have a domain like: 
https://myapp.mybluemix.net

I have a custom domain purchased, but can't find what IP address to point the A records to. I've pinged https://myapp.mybluemix.net and used that IP address but my domain registrar is telling me the IP that's returned is invalid (158.85.156.19)

I've read docs that say that the IP I need for my app pool are available in my bluemix dashboard, but can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You do not want to set an A record directly to your app's IP address. Instead, you want to hit the Bluemix router of the region you are in. The routers have hostnames, so the best way to do this is to use CNAMES instead of A records. The list of hostnames for each region are as follows:

- US South: `secure.us-south.bluemix.net`
- London: `secure.eu-gb.bluemix.net`
- Sydney: `secure.au-syd.bluemix.net`

Comment: More information about custom domains is available in the Bluemix documentation at the following URL:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#domain